# Connect an Android phone to the WiFly board

Tags: android, wifi, adhoc

My team and I are trying to connect an Android phone to the [WiFly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954) board. We are having trouble getting this to connect. Is it that certain phones that do not support this or do support this functionality and what must we do to be able to perform this connection?

We have tried a few things, and it is still not working. If you need further information let me know.

Comment: You may want to consider asking this question at http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Posted it over there too, thanks for the advise.

Comment: Still looking for ideas regarding a solution to this problem, if anyone has anything please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a solution for this issue. We are making the phone act as an access point and having the WiFly board connect to the phone. We tested this by having the WiFly board connected to the phone and had a laptop connect to the phone. We then navigated to the default webpage that is on the WiFly board and we were able to see the page. This seems to be working well and will solve our problem. However, this will drain the phones battery quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a project based on WiFly module and have successfully developed an app that makes a tcp as well as udp connections with the module over the wifi network. No, i didn't need to create my phone as an access point. I can communicate from my phone to WiFly with a wireless router as access point. I could also make it enter command mode so that I can edit its configuration. If you are still searching for a viable solution, I would be happy to provide you with my code.

EDIT: Below is the entire code for the app i made. It has been used to connect to WiFly in a Home Automation project.

The MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ToggleButton toggleButton1;
    private TcpClient mTcpClient;
    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2,spinner3,spinner4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addItemsOnSpinner3();
        addItemsOnSpinner4();

        new connectTask().execute("");
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        Button button_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        button_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + " " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()) + " " + "ON";

                //sends the message to the server
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
            });
            Button button_send1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send1);
            button_send1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + " " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()) + " " + "OFF";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_intensity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_intensity);
            button_intensity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + " " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()) + " " + String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItem());

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_turnon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_turnon);
            button_turnon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = String.valueOf(spinner4.getSelectedItem()) + " ON";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_turnoff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_turnoff);
            button_turnoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = String.valueOf(spinner4.getSelectedItem()) + " OFF";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            toggleButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Is the toggle on?
                    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

                    if (on) {
                        String message = "$$$";

                        //sends the message to the server
                        if (mTcpClient != null) {
                            mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        String message = "exit\r";

                        //sends the message to the server
                        if (mTcpClient != null) {
                            mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                });
            Button button_led1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_led1);
            button_led1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = "set sys iofunc 0x1\r";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_led2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_led2);
            button_led2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = "set sys iofunc 0x2\r";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_led3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_led3);
            button_led3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = "set sys iofunc 0x4\r";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
            button_reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = "set sys iofunc 0x0\r";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
            button_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = "save\r";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
            Button button_reboot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reboot);
            button_reboot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String message = "reboot\r";

                    //sends the message to the server
                    if (mTcpClient != null) {
                        mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            });
    }


         // add items into spinner dynamically
            public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

            spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("load1");
            list.add("load2");
            list.add("load3");
            list.add("load4");
            list.add("load5");
            list.add("load6");
            list.add("load7");
            list.add("load8");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            public void addItemsOnSpinner3() {

                spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Default");
                list.add("10");
                list.add("20");
                list.add("30");
                list.add("40");
                list.add("50");
                list.add("60");
                list.add("70");
                list.add("80");
                list.add("90");
                list.add("100");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner3.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                }

            public void addItemsOnSpinner4() {

                spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("s1");
                list.add("s2");
                list.add("s3");
                list.add("s4");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner4.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }   

            public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TcpClient> {

                @Override
                protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

                    //we create a TcpClient object and
                    mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                        @Override
                        //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                        public void messageReceived(String message) {
                            //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                            publishProgress(message);
                        }
                    });
                    mTcpClient.run();

                    return null;
                }

            }
}
```

And this is the class the creates a tcp client to communicate with WiFly

```
    package com.example.homauto;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.5";
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 2000;
    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */


    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {



        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {

                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {

                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Hope this help somebody in future. The code is applicable to all tcp servers and not just WiFly in particular.

Comment: I know.. But i noticed after posting my reply that the question is almost 3 yrs old and many advancements have been made since then.. However, i'll still post the code... Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Even thought it is old, it is still greatly appreciated! Thanks for lending your knowledge and it will help someone. =D

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is with infrastructure (clients of an access point) vs. ad-hoc (peer-to-peer) wireless networking modes.

The easiest would be if you have an access point that both devices can connect to.  Directly connecting them may be a bit harder, as you have to either get both working in ad-hoc mode or one has to be willing to play access point.

Comment: The wifly board can act in adhoc mode, getting the android phone to do adhoc mode is the difficult part. We are aware that android does not support this feature without rooting. However we are wanting consumers to be able to do this without rooting. I will contact android developers and see if they have any insight. Will post findings here when i get an answer.

Comment: You may be better off trying to get the wifly board to play access point (or using something else that can instead).  It's ironic that the smarter of the pair of devices would be being the limiting partner, but that's vendor lockdown for you....

Comment: Chris, we are using the wifly board as the 'access point'. And we have to get the phone directly connected to the wifly, no mitm. And when i say access point, i am using that loosely, because the phone will be doing the connecting, the wifly will just accept the connection.

Comment: If the wifly is functioning as an access point to create an infrastructure network, rather than as a peer in an ad-hoc network, then you shouldn't have much trouble connecting, unless you use a wireless security scheme that the phone doesn't support.  You might try it temporarily as an open network.  Also verify you can connect a laptop to the wifly and can connect the phone to a different access point.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternate solution not requiring root, see [this](http://sailboatinstruments.blogspot.ca/2012/10/talking-to-android-phone-through-wi-fi.html).